# Converting an ATSC TS to MKV, including all audio tracks and closed-captioning from FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

I'm guessing this can be done somehow, because I've seen programs that are a GUI front-end to FFMPEG that essentially do this, but I'm trying to figure it out from a command-line in Ubuntu. I want to transcode from an MPEG2 video stream from an ATSC recording to h264 but just keep all audio channels as is. I would also like to convert closed-captioning to a subtitle track within the final MKV wrapper. Also, is it possible to mark at least the primary audio track and subtitle tracks as being "**En**glish"? To make it even more awesome, making this a BASH script where I can name the input file and have it save it as the same name but change it to .mkv would make it perfect. I am not knowledgeable to write the script from scratch, nor do I know the proper variables for the FFMPEG command.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky, but here's a working method:

```
INFILE=input.ts
OUTFILE=output.mkv
ffmpeg \
  -i "${INFILE}" \
  -f lavfi -i movie="${INFILE}[out+subcc]" \
  -map 0 -map 1:s \
  -codec:v libx264 \
  -codec:a copy \
  -codec:s srt \
  -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng \
  "${OUTFILE}"
```

Here, `input.ts` and `output.mkv` are your desired input MPEG-TS and output Matroska files, respectively. Generalizing to a script is left as an exercise for the reader.

Interpreting the parameters, line by line:

`-i ...` is the input file.

`-f lavfi -i ...` allows us to extract the embedded caption stream.

`-map 0 -map 1:s` selects the streams for output.

`-codec:v libx264` tells ffmpeg to convert video to H.264.

`-codec:a copy` copies all audio streams to the output unchanged.

`-codec:s srt` tells ffmpeg to convert the embedded captions to SRT.

`-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng` sets the subtitle stream language to English.

Notes:

- I've only used this with over-the-air ATSC streams including what I assume are EIA-608 captions. I have no idea if it works with QAM (cable) recordings, though I expect it does.
- You may have problems with input file names containing certain characters, even if you put the file name in quotes.
- This will copy all audio streams. If you only want the first one, you'll need to explicitly map individual streams from input 0.
- Chances are the audio streams already have a language set. If they don't, add another -metadata option to set the audio stream language, too.
- You will likely want to experiment with the video encoding quality using the -crf option. If your input video is interlaced, you may also want to deinterlace and scale to 720p by adding `-filter:v bwdif=0,scale=1280:720` after the `-map` line(s).

Comment: Well done.  My files had additional non-video/audio streams, which required me to replace -map 0 with explicit mappings for video and audio (-map 0:v -map 0:a gave me all video and all audio streams). Thanks for this, I've been trying to salvage embedded cc's for years!